# Executing an SQL search to "get" a module in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, module

The variable $moduleart corresponds to a minifeed module that I created, and the sqli search query "should" result in displaying the corresponding minifeed (each minifeed displays posts from a specific blog category, i.e. arts). The users on my site subscribe to specific blog categories that are saved in their sql data. That is why I am trying to run the sql queries, so that based on their data, ONLY the specific blog minifeed that they have subscribed to will appear on their homepage. HOWEVER, I have inserted this code into Flexi Custom Code (a module that allows you to insert PHP files and code), and the module works because I tested other PHP code in it, but when I put the code in from below, nothing happens. Please help!

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("*****", "*****", "*****", "*****");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );

$moduleart = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'ArtsARRA');


$sqlarts = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE              '%MINIARTS%'";

while ($rowarts = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlarts))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($moduleart);
}


mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Nothing happening, or a blank screen, the "white screen of death" in PHP means "go look in your error log".  There's likely a fatal error that has occurred and it will be detailed there.  You should always turn up error reporting and display errors on screen in development.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: (or whatever Joomla's preferred method of enabling display_errors is)

Comment: I have error reporting on right now, and it shows errors in the bottom right of the screen for all other issues I've had. For this there are actually no errors shown. My homepage just appears as normal. Do you see any flaws in the PHP code itself? (thank you for your help)

Comment: I don't see any syntax problems. This would only produce any output if matching rows were returned from the query, so if there aren't any matching....Beyond that I can't help much as I'm not well versed with Joomla.

Comment: well thank you for your input! I'll keep working on it